# Can I send Bluetooth advertising packets with Constant Tone Extension from a smartphone?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Bluetooth 5.1 introduced the ability to include a "Constant Tone Extension" into an Advertising packet. On the receive side, a suitable device can perform Angle-of-Arrival estimation using this information. I have experimented with this technology using BLE EVK devices (Nordic).

My question is can I use a 5.1 compatible smartphone as the transmitter? How can I enable CTE in the advertising packet? Is it something that can be configured through a suitable app and android SDK, or do I need lower-level access to the phones Bluetooth modem (drivers)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since CTE is an optional feature for Bluetooth 5.1, the answer is clear: it depends.
Bluetooth direction finding is not yet supported by Android, so it would require a manufacturer-specific API to enable CTE (if it is supported by the  smartphone hardware).

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Do you have any suggestions for specific phones which may support that?

Alternatively, is it possible to modify the source code in an Android / Linux phone to do that? Any pointers towards this direction (i.e. open-source phones with good documentation) would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help in this respect. I am not aware of any smartphone platform that already supports this feature.